# Hit-testing on entire area of custom FrameworkElement that contains transparent elements

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

I've got a custom control that inherits from `FrameworkElement`. It contains a `Visual` that contains transparent areas. I'm trying to make the entire control area respond to hit tests, but at the moment, when I click on part of the control that displays a transparent area of the `Visual`, the click passes through to the underlying layer.

Is there a way of making the entire control hit-testable without using a hack?

I'd like to stay away from techniques like painting the background of the `Visual` white, or adding a `Border` around the custom control that has the same event handler set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a transparent brush and it will respond to hit testing.

For example, if you have null background brush, then hit testing will pass right through.

If you use Brushes.Transparent as a background or fill area, then it will work with hit testing.

Answer (score 1):

using Background or Fill = "{x:Null}" which is the default for some classes like Grid is not the same as Background or Fill = "Transparent". Setting Transparent as the background/fill color should work.

Comment: I've seen this presented as a solution for similar problems, but my control inherits directly from `FrameworkElement` and thus doesn't expose these properties.